# When I start Appium using commands it's not detecting elements

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

When I start Appium though GUI it's able to detect elements but when I start Appium using commands it's not detecting elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use all the Appium apps latest version. If any of the Appium apps is out of date than it may cause this type of behavior.

1. To update Appium CLI, run the following command:

   npm update -g appium
2. To update the Appium GUI, download the latest version from [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases).
3. Also use latest Appium binding depending on which language you are using.
4. Don't forget to update your Android SDK.